# How to obtain Drupal session cookie via an XMLRPC request?

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization, cookies

I would like to implement single sign-on to Drupal and other site (not PHP) via xmlrpc.

Is there a way to make an xmlrpc call with user name & password and in return obtain information on success of authentication and the session cookie - so that we could set the cookie and log in to both sites at once?

Answer (score 2):

The [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module does this. See its user.login service. Core Drupal does not offer this service via XML-RPC.